# How do i removing trailing zero's on a float

Tags: android

After a calculate I have a float value
10.5, 10.0 etc

ie some times the decimal value is .0

whats the best approach to not show .0 ie I would rather show
10.5, 10

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Simple but lengthy.

Convert your float to string. Split the string using "." as a delimeter. So the output of this is an array of 2 strings. That is the first element in the array is something that comes before decimal point and the second element is the array value after decimal.

According to you, if after decimal if the element is 0, then you prefer an integer, rather than a float value. So follow the below code:

```
float a=10.0;
String[] arr=a.toString().split(".");
if(Integer.parseInt(arr[1])==0) //Means, after decimal it is a 0 eg. 10.0
      System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(arr[0]); //So printing only the first half
else
      System.out.println(a); //Means after decimal there is some value. eg. 10.5
```

Hope this might have helped you.

Comment: This was my first approach but the split operation didnt work, ill try again thanks

Comment: i tried yours and got the same problem as i was getting ,for some reason if i escape the period ie split("\\."); then it works

Answer (score 0):

Do not confuse the float's value with its representation when you output it:

For example, the float value may be 10.000001 but it you format it with two digits after the decimal, you end up with a string, in essence, "10.00".

There are multiple ways to format floats in Java:

- Just convert it to a string with `String.valueOf(10.0)` (or the shorter form `"" + 10.0`
- Use a `DecimalFormatter` and supply a format string like "#.##" to always keep two digits after the decimal even if the float has non-zero digits beyond the cutoff. This will return a formatted string.
- Use `System.out.format()` and supply a format string like "%10.2f" to, again, keep 2 digits. Note that this outputs to the system console.

I will leave it to you to look those up if you want to use them.

Now, for your question, you seem to want an indeterminate number of digits after the decimal but never that one zero.

```
float f = 10.0;
String a = "" + f;
if (a.endsWith(".0")) {
    if (a.equals(".0)) {
        a = "0";
    } else {
        a = a.substring(0, a.length() - 2);
    }
}
```

Which will strip off the trailing ".0" and, if nothing is left, add the integer part "0".